# How to get details of top CPU using servers in KQL

Tags: performance, azure-data-explorer, kql

All our servers have the Log Analytics agent installed. The agent is configured to capture performance counters info. I can easily get an overview of CPU usage on all servers by firing this query:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
| summarize HourlyUsage = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h),  Computer 
| render timechart
```

I would like to create a graph showing the CPU usage of the top 10 heaviest loaded servers. I created a `KQL` query to get the top 10 of CPU using servers:

```
let TopCPUMaxServers = Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize Max_CPU = max(CounterValue) by Computer, CounterName
| top 10 by Max_CPU  asc nulls last;
```

This query gives me the list of interesting servers. Now I would like to get the performance counters of this list. When I try this:

```
let TopCPUMaxServers = Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize Max_CPU = max(CounterValue) by Computer, CounterName
| top 10 by Max_CPU  asc nulls last;
Perf | join (TopCPUMaxServers) on Computer 
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer
| render timechart
```

I only get the measurements from the first query displayed on a time chart. (basically 10 values)
How can I get the performance counters for the servers obtained in the first query?

Regards,
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [join kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) is "innerunique" which returns the first match. You can use a the "leftouter" kind but for this scenario the "in" operator will be simpler and will likely perform better:

```
let TopCPUMaxServers = Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize Max_CPU = max(CounterValue) by Computer, CounterName
| top 10 by Max_CPU  asc nulls last
| project Computer;
Perf 
| where Computer in (TopCPUMaxServers)
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, it seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use next variant using in() operator:

```
let TopCPUMaxServers = Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize Max_CPU = max(CounterValue) by Computer, CounterName
| top 10 by Max_CPU  asc nulls last
| project Computer;
Perf 
| where Computer in (TopCPUMaxServers)
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, it seems to work!